# brackets quote in html

Tags: html

can anyone explain to me the below code:

```
<li><a class="xo-gbnavmod3" href="<{xoAppUrl modules/tdgallery/}>" accesskey="g"  title="<{$smarty.const.THEME_MODULE3_DESC}>"><{$smarty.const.THEME_MODULE3}></a></li>
```

What is <{}> in html ? the link above is tdgallery that is wrong and i want to change it to tadgallery but when i changed it, the link in my website also navigate to the old wrong link. What should i do ?

Thanks for you helping

Comment: Is this the code sent to the browser?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something that uses the PHP Smarty Template Engine.

See: http://www.smarty.net

*** EDIT *** My mistake...it actually appears to be XOOPS.